Allow Woocommerce Virtual Download Access with Custom Order Status
I'm using Woocommerce to manage orders where some customers pay by check and some pay by card. I created a custom order status called "Shipped Need Payment" to denote that a customer has provided a Purchase Order, we shipped the physical product, and we are still waiting on a check.
This works great for physical products, but for virtual products, my custom status does not activate download access. I have to mark the order as Completed for access to activate, even if I manually add downloadable permissions on the order page. To be clear, if I get a Purchase Order, I want to activate digital access but keep the order in Shipped Need Payment status to denote that I'm still waiting on the check.
Any ideas how I can modify my custom order status to allow download access instead of only relying on the "Completed" status?
    register_post_status( 'wc-shipped-need-pay', array(
    'label'                     => 'Shipped Need Payment',
    'public'                    => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
    'exclude_from_search'       => false,
    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Shipped Need Payment (%s)', 'Shipped Need Payment    (%s)' )
    ) );

